# managed object value is randomly null (Sample project included)

Tags: ios, core-data

After saving data (10 records) to an entity, I am processing a fetch request to get all data again:

```
//Saving data
- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didEndElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName{

    //Save to coredata


        song = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Song"
                                             inManagedObjectContext:context];
        [song setValue:title forKey:@"title"];

        [song setValue:songLink forKey:@"songWebLink"];
        NSLog(@"Song link : %@",songLink);//Never get NULL


        [song setValue:albumLink forKey:@"albumImageLink"];

        NSError *error = nil;
        if (![context save:&error]) {
            NSLog(@"Whoops, couldn't save: %@", [error localizedDescription]);
        }else{

            NSLog(@"Record saved correctly");
        }
}
```

Saving above is working fine and I debugged very carefully all data before being saved to the context to ensure none of the attributes is `NULL`.

The problem is always with the `songWebLink` attribute, sometimes it gets null when I try ot get it back below:

```
- (void)parserDidEndDocument:(NSXMLParser *)parser{

    NSEntityDescription *songEntity=[NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Song" inManagedObjectContext:context];
    NSFetchRequest *fetch=[[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
    [fetch setEntity:songEntity];
    NSError *fetchError;
    NSArray *fetchedSongs=[context executeFetchRequest:fetch error:&fetchError];

    NSMutableArray *songs = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    for (NSManagedObject *songObject in fetchedSongs) {
    //here is the issue: this for loop will go through 10 iterations, songWebLink is randomly NULL, sometimes it's the fourth iteration, sometimes the 8th, sometimes the 5th.
        NSLog(@"song web link: %@",[songObject valueForKey:@"songWebLink"]);//albumImageLink and title attributes are fine
    }
}
```

The issue is that when I `NSLog` the `songWebLink`, it gets NULL, once for the 4th iteration, then for 6th, then 2nd etc. It's randomly assigning NULL to an attribute when fetching. When saving data, I make sure there is no `NULL` value for `songWebLink`. So I bet on something else to be the cause of this issue.

Any thoughts?

**EDIT**

Here is how the MOC is initialized:

**AppDelegate.m:**

```
- (NSManagedObjectContext *)managedObjectContext
{
    if (_managedObjectContext != nil) {
        return _managedObjectContext;
    }

    NSPersistentStoreCoordinator *coordinator = [self persistentStoreCoordinator];
    if (coordinator != nil) {
        _managedObjectContext = [[NSManagedObjectContext alloc] init];//I tried initWithConcurrencyType:NSMainQueueConcurrencyType
        [_managedObjectContext setPersistentStoreCoordinator:coordinator];
    }
    return _managedObjectContext;
}
```

Getting MOC object to use it in a different class :

```
AppDelegate *appDelegate = (AppDelegate*)[[UIApplication sharedApplication]delegate];
context = [appDelegate managedObjectContext];
```

**Sample project:**
If you think you need to get a look on the app project, I made a simplified version on which I reproduced the bug, you can download it [here](http://www.filedropper.com/ituneschartservicesongs).

Comment: You are saving the context too much. Maybe that's causing the problem. I'd create the `NSManagedObject` at `parser:didEndElement:namespaceURI:qualifiedName:` and save them all once in `parserDidEndDocument:`.

Comment: Hi, I thought about it already and test it, but didn't work either.

Comment: Try setting the `songWebLink` property to a hard-coded string. If the problem goes away, take a closer look at the actual values coming in. The only other thing I can think of is make sure you're using the context and it's objects on the queue associated with the context. Threading issues can appear random.

Comment: Hi Timothy, I updated my post by adding how the MOC is gotten from the AppDelegate. Please have a look and try to elaborate your comment is an answer below. I guess there is something wrong dealing with the MOC as you said but didn't be able to figure it out yet.

Comment: If your context object becomes deallocated, you can wind up with weird behavior in you entities (specifically attributes will be null).  Are you keeping a strong reference to your context?

Comment: @JeffCompton, yes I checked that, the context is never deallocated and it's a strong property indeed.

Comment: I make a simplified version of my app to  reproduce the bug and uploaded it here so anyone who can help me fixing that:http://www.filedropper.com/ituneschartservicesongs

Comment: In `parserDidEndDocument` delegate method, I tried to fetch and debug data and there I got random `null` value. I tried to apply parent-child MOC but some discussion here don't recommend that approach.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After days trying to figure this out, I choosed to go for [MagicalRecord](https://github.com/magicalpanda/MagicalRecord) as it simplifies a lot of fetching headaches. If anyone could figure out the issue and help me out, I will consider his answer as the accepted one.

Answer (score 0):

Give this a try:

Include this in your fetch request

```
[fetch setIncludesPropertyValues:YES];
```

Iterate through the returned objects like this:

```
for (Song *songObject in fetchedSongs) {
    //here is the issue: this for loop will go through 10 iterations, songWebLink is randomly NULL, sometimes it's the fourth iteration, sometimes the 8th, sometimes the 5th.
    NSLog(@"song web link: %@",songObject.songWebLink);//albumImageLink and title attributes are fine
}
```

I'm not 100% sure this will fix it but it will help in finding the problem if it doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

From the look of it, you're running on main all the time so I don't think there is a threading/context problem.

It's likely the data type returned by the XML parser doesn't match the CoreData data type.

Instead of logging like this:

```
NSLog(@"Song link : %@",songLink);//Never get NULL
```

try:

```
NSLog(@"Song link : %@",[song valueForKey:@"songWebLink"]);
NSLog(@"Song link class : %@",[songLink class]);
```

I bet you'll start seeing your null values in the first log. The second log will hopefully tell you what class is actually being returned by the XML parser. You'll have to handle it appropriately.